# Chasing the Truth not showing up?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I've delivered the 5 vehicles to Epsilon or whatever (Assuming the Truth).  Got an email saying they'd be in touch.  Can't get it to show up, tried everything.  Starting to get annoyed at all the GTA 5 glitches.  *sigh

Comment: Did you wait a few days after receiving the email? I think I had to wait 2 or 3 days before the icon actually appeared on the map (sleeping in your safehouse to minimize the waiting time should be working)

Comment: It's possible it did and I missed it.  But now I'm like WAAAAYYYYY past that.  probably 20 days GTA 5 time.  Ya think i'll never be able to do those missions now?

Answer (score -1):

Just wait a few game days and the next mission should show up. Try sleeping several times if you don't feel like playing a long time

Comment: A comment from the OP mentions he has waited approx. 20 days.  Do you have a source that would give some kind of number for the amount of time needed to wait?

Comment: No i do not have a source other than personal experience. I would say 2-5 days wait and it is glitched if you have to wait over 5 days.